# I want to restore a device I previously selected to 'Forget Device' on Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, ipod-nano

I have Apple Nano 7th generation.  I turned on Bluetooth and a device was recognized. I selected Forget this Device.  I now want to restore the device. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to re-pair it. Follow the manufacturer instructions for both devices to enter pairing mode and you will be able to reconnect them. Forgetting the device does not block it, just unpairs them.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The nano automatically begins to pair when I go on to bluetooth. My Bluetooth earbud begins to pair when I press the on/off button. The nano still does not recognize the earbud. I previously asked the nano to forget the earbud.

Comment: Please don't post clarifications as answers, either edit your question to add details or use comments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try restarting the iPod.

You can do this by holding the power button and home button until the screen turns black, and then releasing both buttons and holding down the power button again until the Apple logo appears.